# Select data from two tables sqlite and return it to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, express, react-native-sqlite-storage

i have two tables :

**1 - Users**

| IdUser | FirstName | LastName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | last1 |
| 2 | name2 | last2 |

**2 - Books**

| IdBook | NameBook | IdUser |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | book1 | 1 |
| 2 | book2 | 1 |
| 3 | book3 | 2 |

I am using **React-Native** and **react-native-sqlite-storage**

```
listofBooks() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      var books= [];    
      this.initDB()
        .then(db => {
          db.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * from Users INNER JOIN Books ON Users.IdUser= Books.IsUser',
            ).then(([tx, results]) => {
              var len = results.rows.length;
              if (len > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                  let row = results.rows.item(i);
                  const { IdUser, FirstName, LastName, NameBook } = row;
                  books.push({ IdUser, FirstName, LastName, NameBook  });
                }
                resolve(JSON.stringify(books));
              }
            });
          })
            .then(result => {
              this.closeDatabase(db);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

the function return this json

```
[
  {
    "IdUser": 1,
    "FirstName": "name1",
    "LastName": "last1",
    "NameBook": "book1",
  },
  {
    "IdUser": 1,
    "FirstName": "name1",
    "LastName": "last1",
    "NameBook": "book2",
  },
  {
    "IdUser": 2,
    "FirstName": "name2",
    "LastName": "last2",
    "NameBook": "book3",
  }
]
```

but I would like my json be like that

```
[
  {
    "IdUser": 1,
    "FirstName": "name1",
    "LastName": "last1",
    "NameBook": ["book1", "book2"],
  },
  {
    "IdUser": 2,
    "FirstName": "name2",
    "LastName": "last2",
    "NameBook": "book3",
  }
]
```

is there a library for (react-native) that allows me to solve this problem easily ?
thanks for help.